# Uploading a file in squarespace with a custom link structure

Tags: squarespace

First of all, thankyou for anyone who responds for help. It is much much appreciated.

I have been tasked with uploading two xml files into a squarespace site, for use with an app which connects to them both.

The url structure for the file is meant to be: example.com/app/file.xml

Squarespace only allows the following URL: example.com/s/file.xml

The app will only work with: example.com/app/file.xml

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a potential work around for this. Ensure the name of the file you are uploading has no spaces, capital letters or special characters in it. Then:

1. Upload the file [via the link editor](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205813928-Uploading-and-managing-files).
2. Go to Settings > Advanced > URL Mappings
3. Add `/app/myfile.xml -> /s/myfile.xml 301` as a URL Mapping in the text area (where `myfile.xml` is the name of your file)
4. Click Save

You can view a working example [here](https://seal-orca-y998.squarespace.com/app/note.xml). The temporary, view-only password is: `password`. In that example, the file name is note.xml. You would use your own file name.

**Important note when testing redirects in Squarespace**: Squarespace caches redirects in your browser. So, when testing to see that your redirect is working, make sure to use a Private/Incognito window and close the window between tests. Alternatively, you can continually clear your browser's cache between tests.

If (and only if) you get the above to work on your site similarly to how it works in my example, then test it using your app. If it works in your browser but your app doesn't seem to be able to access the file, ensure that you have a paid site and that your site is not password protected (the app may not be able to get through the password).

If it still does not work, it likely has to do with the `Content-Disposition` response header that’s sent with files uploaded via the link editor. Your final alternative is to enable [developer mode](https://developers.squarespace.com/quick-start) and add the file to the `/assets` folder (then edit the URL mapping accordingly to use `/assets` instead of `/s`).

If you need dev. mode (and you might not), note that turning on dev. mode isn't recommended unless you understand the ramifications, especially if this is a live site or site you've already spent a lot of time on setting up. Alternatively, you could quickly setup a new demo, turn on dev. mode, and test the solution that way without worrying. Using dev. mode and accessing the /assets folder requires familiarity with Git and other development tools.

Comment: Hi there - thankyou for your answer. I see your link and see it works - however mine still goes to a 404. Did you manage this with your first suggestion or the 2nd via assets?

I can PM you the link if it's possible.

Comment: Also the url must use the domain itself rather than the hosted squarespace default address.

Comment: The example posted is a trial I started just for this question/answer. I started the trial, uploaded the file via the file manager (https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206543827), and added the redirect. The example uses the `.squarespace.com` domain only because it is a trial (I'd have to pay to use a custom domain). On a paid site, you can use your custom domain just the same. To troubleshoot, first, upload the file. Then add the link to your original question. That will allow you and others to verify that at least you have the file uploaded properly.

Comment: When testing you must use an Incognito/Private browser window, closing the window between tests. That is because your browser will cache the redirect and, no matter what you do, you'll keep seeing a 404 page. Alternatively, you can continually clear you browser cache. This caching of redirects trips up many people, myself included. You must clear your cache for each test of the redirect or clear your cache between each test.

Comment: Ok great, I'll try this shortly. Again, thankyou.

The link is meant to be via an app so I'm not sure the app would accept but we'll see. Will update you on progress later today.

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain your upload process? I know there is tutorial and I have followed it, but somehow I must be doing this wrong.

The link you supplied with password works every time with or without cache. I keep getting the same error with mine.

With regards to adding the link - I'm not sure I can as I think this is a developer URL.

I also cannot see the assets folder even with developer mode.

Thankyou for taking the time to setup a trial account. :)

Comment: I've added a link to the original answer above which contains a video that shows the exact upload process. Note that it will be easier if your file contains no spaces or capital letters. My example will work regardless of clearing cache, that is correct, but that will not be the case while testing and setting up a new redirect for the first time. Please share the link to the file once you've uploaded it. Yes, you can do that. It will look similar to this (but will use your site's domain instead): https://seal-orca-y998.squarespace.com/s/note.xml . You don't need dev mode.

Comment: I also heavily edited the original answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi Brandon, sorry I forgot to reply to this sooner. This answer was correct, so thankyou for taking the time to help. The mapping problem I had is the URLs were the wrong way round. Kudos to you sir! :)